# Displaying Text View on top of Seekbar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am trying to implement a seek bar which has text 'Confirm to Slide' with a custom thumb. Using below code I am able to get custom thumb and seek bar. Please suggest me on how to display the text on top of seek bar with an example if possible. Below is my code

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumbsize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="12dp"
        android:maxHeight="36dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you want is to write your own custom view. Please refer to [Creating Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) and [Android: draw a custom view](https://hackernoon.com/android-draw-a-custom-view-ef79fe2ff54b). But before doing that, do search Android Arsenal. There might already be a library there for you.

Comment: https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this using vertical LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text goes here"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I wanted custom text to be displayed above seek bar(on top). The one you suggested will display textview and seekbar.

Comment: There is no label property for SeekBar. My suggestion will give you similar functionality.

Comment: Of course, You could create a custom view and implement it yourself but I think this will be a major overhead for most use cases.

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but I am not getting the expected result. Creating custom view would be a major task for me. So checking if there is any alternate solution.